# UE4. Dynamic texture creation and mipmaps

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Good day!

UE4's UTexture2D has CreateTransient static method which allows to create texture dynamically with c++. It works fine. But UTexture2D has also MipGenSettings property which is used in editor and controls mipmap creation. It would be nice to have something similar in runtime in game not in editor for mipmap generation. Is there any solution for this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found these:

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/424643/no-mipmap-support-for-dynamic-2d-texture.html

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/193827/how-to-get-texture-pixels-using-utexturerendertarg.html

It looks like other people we're struggling with this as well. According to the posts UE4 might have fixed it and/or the community came up with a work around. The first link looks like a workaround, the second link is a discussion.

Comment: Thanks Katianie. Unfortunatelly as I see current UE4 version (4.19), macro still denies MipGenSettings in game mode. The main idea to get engine mip map generator to work. Both links as I undestand point to manual mip map generation.